# Incluir 2 IEnumerable em 1 View!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Olá sou novo aqui e estou com problemas com a minha aplicação!
Quero listar 2 lista em uma view (Promoções e Lançamentos).
O código está assim!

(classe Promocao)

```
namespace SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.Entidades
{
    public class CadPromocao
    {
        public int PromocaoId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string NomeBrinde { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(classe Lançamento)

```
namespace SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.Entidades
{
    public class CadLancamento
    {
        public int LancamentoId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string NomeBrinde { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(as View Models das classes)

```
namespace SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels
{
    public class CadLancamentoViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int LancamentoId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string NomeBrinde { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels
{
    public class CadPromocaoViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int PromocaoId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string NomeBrinde { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(View Model que recebe as 2 classes)

```
namespace SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento
{
    public class PromocaoLancamentoViewModel
    {
        private IEnumerable<CadLancamentoViewModel> lancamento;
        private IEnumerable<CadPromocaoViewModel> promocao;

        public PromocaoLancamentoViewModel(IEnumerable<CadLancamentoViewModel> lancamento, IEnumerable<CadPromocaoViewModel> promocao)
        {
            this.lancamento = lancamento;
            this.promocao = promocao;
        }

        public IEnumerable<CadLancamento> Lancamento { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CadPromocao> Promocao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var promo = Db.CadPromocaos.ToList();
            var promocao = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CadPromocao>, IEnumerable<CadPromocaoViewModel>>(promo);

            var lanc = Db.CadLancamentos.ToList();
            var lancamento = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CadLancamento>, IEnumerable<CadLancamentoViewModel>>(lanc);

            var promocaoLancamento = new PromocaoLancamentoViewModel(lancamento, promocao);

            return View(promocaoLancamento);
        }
```

(minha VIEW Index)

```
@model IEnumerable<SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento.PromocaoLancamentoViewModel>

<div class="container body-content">

            @foreach (var item in Model.GetEnumerator().Current.Promocao)
            {
                <div id="conteudo_promocao">
                    <div id="caixa_promocao">
                        <img width="100%" height="250" src="@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })" />
                        <h3>Código: @item.Codigo</h3>
                        <h4>@item.Descricao</h4>
                        <div id="link_caixa">
                            <p>@Html.ActionLink("Pedir Orçamento", "Orcamento", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

(Agora o erro que está dando é esse)

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento.PromocaoLancamentoViewModel',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento.PromocaoLancamentoViewModel]'.

O que faço, estou a 3 dias tentando levar as 2 lista para a view e não consigo

Answer (score 0):

Na sua view, basta você alterar o seu model para usar a sua classe `PromocaoLancamentoViewModel`

```
    @model SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento.PromocaoLancamentoViewModel

    <div class="container body-content">    
                @foreach (var item in Model.Lancamento)
                {                    
                       ...
                }

                @foreach (var item in Model.Promocao)
                {                    
                       ...
                }
    </div>
```

Comment: Pablo deu certo, uhullll, muito obrigado Pablo!

Answer (score 0):

Na sua view, você pede um `IEnumerable<>`, enquanto deveria solicitar somente um objeto único da sua ViewModel (afinal, é o que você está associando no seu Controller):

Apenas altere a primeira linha de sua View:

```
@model SiteJapaBrindesDDD.MVC.ViewModels.IndexPromocaoLancamento.PromocaoLancamentoViewModel
```